# Host not responding - vCenter

Tags: networking, virtualization, virtual-machines, cloud, vmware-vcenter

Few days ago I configured a new vCenter server behind the NAT for my VMware Hosts. Everything is working perfectly on the Management LAN, but the problem is when I'm trying to add a server outside my Management LAN - then I'm getting information "Not Responding" after 30-60 seconds - so I tried to troubleshoot this problem and I found that my host 4 on public IP (outside management LAN) is connected to vCenter on the private IP address (When I accessed my host via vSphere I saw a message "This host is currently being mamanged by the Vcenter Server with IP address 10.0.50.2) so I changed the IP address in the config file on host 4 in /etc/vmware/vpxa/vpxa.cfg to

```
  <serverIp>80.25.xxx.1</serverIP>
  <preserveServerIp>true</preserveServerIp>
```

Then I saved it and I restarted vCenter agent service. But now I've got different problem - when I'm trying to reconnect to the host via vCenter - I'm getting information "This host is currently being managed by the vCenter Server with IP address 80.25.xxx.1"

So the question: what I have to do to be able to add any VMware host outside my management lan on public IP address? I want to keep my vCenter on private IP address.

On my firewall I have created a NAT from 80.25.xxx.1:902 to 10.0.50.2:902 for heartbeat - is that enough?

Information about my servers:

vCenter: 10.0.50.2

Host 1: 10.0.50.3

Host 2: 10.0.50.4

Host 3: 10.0.50.5

Host 4: 80.25.xxx.252

Juniper Firewall: 80.25.xxx.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you NAT is asymmetric. Outgoing traffic from your `Host 4` has source address of the firewall (80.25.xxx.1). I assume you use policy based NAT, so in that case on your Juniper firewall you need to add a separate rule for outgoing traffic from `Host 4` to have source address 80.25.xxx.252.